# Array not storing data from form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am creating a user settings page allowing members to update their information. The information displays, however once changed doesn't update on the database, although no errors are produced and the success page is displayed. I have tried echoing the array and it appears to be blank meaning it's not parsing any of the new data.

```
<?php
include ("storescripts/init.php");
protect_page();
if (empty($_POST) === false) {
$required_fields = array('mem_email','mem_first_name','mem_last_name');
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) == true) {
        $errors[] = 'Fields marked with an asterisk are required';
        break 1;
    }
}
if (empty($errors) === true) {
    if (filter_var($_POST['mem_email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'A valid email address is required';
    } else if(user_exists($_POST['mem_email']) === 1 && $member_data['mem_email'] !== $_POST['mem_email']) {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry, the email \'' . htmlentities($_POST['mem_email']) . '\' is already in use';
    }
}
}
if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {

$update_data = array(
        'mem_first_name' => $_POST['mem_first_name'],
        'mem_last_name' => $_POST['mem_last_name'],
        'mem_email' => $_POST['mem_email'],
        'allow_email' => ($_POST['allow_email']) ? 1 : 0);

        update_user($session_member_id, $update_data);
        header('Location: settings.php?success=1');
        die();
}
include ("includes/overall/head.php");
?>
<?php include ("includes/overall/template_header.php");?>
<div id="mainDivShort">
    <h1>User Settings</h1>
    <div id="divBreak"></div>
    <?php include ("includes/overall/column_left.php");?>
    <div id="middleContent">
    <?php if (isset($_GET['success']) && isset($_GET['success'])) {
            echo 'Your details have been updated';
            } else {
                if (empty($errors) === false) {
                echo output_errors($errors);
                }?>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <ul>
                <li>First Name*: <br> <input type="text"    name="mem_first_name"
                    value="<?php echo  $member_data['mem_first_name'];?>">
                </li>
                <li>Last Name*: <br> <input type="text"  name="mem_last_name"
                    value="<?php echo  $member_data['mem_last_name'];?>">
                </li>
                <li>Email*: <br> <input type="text" name="mem_email"
                    value="<?php echo $member_data['mem_email'];? >">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="allow_email" <? php if ($member_data['allow_email'] == 1) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>> Would you like to  receive an email about news and promotions?
                </li>
                <li><input type="submit" value="Update">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
        <?php }?>
    </div>
    <?php include ("includes/overall/column_right.php");?>
</div>
<?php include ("includes/overall/template_footer.php");?>
```

And my update_user function

```
function update_user($mem_id, $update_data) {
$update = array();
array_walk($update_data, 'array_sanitize');

foreach ($update_data as $field=>$data) {
    $update[] = '`' . $field . '` = \'' . $data . '\'';
}

mysql_query("UPDATE `members` SET " . implode(', ', $update) . " WHERE `mem_id`= $mem_id");
}
```

Comment: You have a lot of code there .. what is the array you are echoing?

Comment: The array is the $update_data on line 22

Answer (score 0):

do you receive the correct data in your update_user function ?

try this

```
function update_user($mem_id, $update_data) {
    $update = array();
    array_walk($update_data, 'array_sanitize');

    foreach ($update_data as $field=>$data) {
        $update[] = '`' . $field . '` = \'' . $data . '\'';
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE `members` SET " . implode(', ', $update) . " WHERE `mem_id`= $mem_id";
   echo $sql; exit(); 

    //mysql_query("UPDATE `members` SET " . implode(', ', $update) . " WHERE `mem_id`= $mem_id");
    }
```

Fire this $sql output in your db to check if you have sql errors or any other db errors

Comment: The correct data is being displayed, just it doesn't update once change

Comment: you have mentioned on the top your new array is blank ?

Comment: I think it's when the $update_data is being parsed, it's being parsed blank rather than with the new data

Comment: so you have a problem in your POST ? check your $_POST after you post

Comment: I'm getting directed to the success page, so the conditions in the if statement are being met. But if I echo my array and die under before header redirect, my array is shown as Array(), so is blank

Comment: try changing (empty($_POST) === false) to (!empty($_POST)) and (empty($errors) === true) to (empty($_errors))

Comment: Didn't make any difference. Data wasn't updated on the database